# Why is the output unstable and how can I fix it?

Tags: tables, output

I am trying to create a table with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to insert images

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{\bf{BLABLA BLABLABLA}}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 \rowcolor{gray!20} Date & $\theta$ (\degres) & $r$ (UA) & $y$ (UA) & Vitesse (UA/jour) & Vitesse (km/s) & $||\Delta \vec{V}||$ (km/s) & $a$ (km/s\up{2})\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, there are many (many) warnings like this in the log :

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

and the output is not consistent, vertical bars are missing on the left and randomly in columns. Example :
[image: incorrect output]

What is wrong and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Hi. Please paste a Minimal working example, including the preamble and everything instead of your code excerpt. This will make it so much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: It is probably a problem of resolution of your pdf viewer. Try to zoom the table in the viewer and check if the missing lines appear. Or check a hardcopy (printed version) of the page.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, you should (a) get rid of all vertical lines (trust me, they won't be missed...) and (b) omit the horizontal lines as well since they are redundant, given that you're using colors (or, rather, shades of gray) to set off the header row. What I would do, in contrast, is split the information in the header row into two separate rows, to the variables in the upper row and their units (in parentheses) in the next row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{\bfseries BLABLA BLABLABLA}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
 \rowcolor{gray!15} 
 Date & $\theta$  & $r$  & $y$ & Vitesse  & Vitesse  & $\Vert\Delta \vec{V}\Vert$  & $a$ \\
 \rowcolor{gray!15} 
  & (degres) & (UA) & (UA) & (UA/jour) & (km/s) & (km/s) & (km/s\textsuperscript{2})\\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```